# viewing in-app purchase sales

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I can see in my app review that one person has made a purchase on my app however on my sales and trends on my itunes connect I can't see even a single in apps sales made? The app has just been released for 4 days now and was wondering if they update this weekly or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunesConnect doesn't always have the most up to date numbers. All sales and IAP should show up in iTunesConnect, but my experience is that they can be delayed by days.

If you are interested in very good looking sales figures and reporting, you can check out 3rd Party aggregate sites. I use [AppFigures](http://appfigures.com) quite a bit. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! AppFigures is quite helpful, will check it out

Comment: @adit how to implement appFigure API??